# How to resize transparent PNG without causing black background? - PHP GD

Tags: php, gd

The code below replaces the transparent background with a black background.

`imagescale()` seems to cause it.

How can I get this to display without the black background after using `imagescale()`?

```
$im = imagecreatefrompng('ipad.png');   

header('Content-type: image/png');  

$im = imagescale($im, 300);

imagepng($im);
```

Comment: Yes, it turns out you are right. I had already read that answer and tried to make it apply, but couldn't get it to work.  But I went back over it again. I misunderstood that imagecopyresampled takes the place of imagescale. Now it works!